# How to change structure of React .js with Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, new-project

I made CRA project with `--typescript` and did try use `react-app-rewired` for change structure for like this:

```
my-app/
├─ .gitignore
├─ node_modules/
├─ public/ ...
├─ src/
│  └─ components/
|     └─ My-Component
|        └─ Index.tsx
|        └─ Index.test.tsx
|     ...
├─ docs/
|  └─ App.tsx // and here use My-Component
|  └─ Index.tsx
├─ package.json
├─ tsconfig.json
```

Do you have any solution on how to do it? All-time i have problem with import `Index.tsx` and `App.tsx` from `docs/` folder. Also I did try set entry file `entry: "./docs/index.tsx",` in `config-overrides.js` in Webpack config, but The best effect I was get loading Index.tsx but App.tsx show me an error.

[App.tsx error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0D3J.png)

```
const path = require('path');
const {
    getLoader,
    injectBabelPlugin
} = require("react-app-rewired");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
  // The Webpack config to use when compiling your react app for development or production.
  webpack: (config, env) => {
    config = {
      mode: 'development',
      entry: './docs/index.tsx',
      resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
      },
       module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.(tsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: ['babel-loader']
          },
        ]
      },
      plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          template: 'public/index.html'
        })
      ]

    };
    return config;
  }
};
```

The structure must be preserved in this way because I wanted to convert an existing old project for CRA with TS

Any other ways how to change structure of files in CRA?

Comment: For those interested in the topic I don't move the `src` folder but, I will make a new folder for my components. And in src file, I will keep content that was supposed to be in `docs`